# How to generate unique ID's in SSR project (Next.js)

Tags: reactjs, svg, babeljs, next.js

I have a project that requires some marketing pages to be built that includes X amount of SVG's on the page but I'm noticing that they're all sharing the same ID so all of the SVG's are rendering the same image. Without having to manually add id's to each svg is there a way to automatically generate id's in a next.js project? I'm noticing this issue is specific to SSR.

Comment: @RobertLongson would you be able to elaborate on importing via object? I'm currently importing the svg's like normal react components eg. `import SvgImage from "./file.svg"`

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Need to change

```
{
  "presets": [
    "next/babel"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "inline-react-svg"
  ]
}
```

To

```
{
  "presets": [
    "next/babel"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "inline-react-svg",
      {
        "svgo": {
          "plugins": [
            {
              "cleanupIDs": true
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```